# c++ Output stream not working with templates and namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, namespaces, ostream

I have the following code:

```
#include <fstream>

// Removing this namespace (keeping the content) makes it work
namespace baz {

class Bar {
};

}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, baz::Bar & value) {
  return stream;
}

// Removing this namespace (keeping the content) makes it work
namespace goo {

template <class Type>
struct Point {
};

// Removing this function makes it work
template <class Type>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Point<Type> &point);

void foo() {
  baz::Bar test;
  std::ofstream stream;
  stream << test;
}

}
```

It does not compile on MSVC and fails with the following error message:

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'baz::Bar' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

However, if I remove any of the two namespaces (keeping all the contents) or remove the templated `<<` function for the `Point` class, everything works fine.

**Is this a bug in MSVC? How can I make it compile without removing the namespaces or the function?**

Comment: Try `using ::operator<<;` or move it to `namespace baz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in your code. The overload set for functions is build in multiple stages:

1. From the current scope outwards find a matching function name. When a name is found in a namespace add all overloads defined in this namespace to the overload set and stop this process.
2. Add all overloads found by argument dependent look-up (ADL) to the overload set.
3. Determine if the overload set contains a unique matching and best overload. If so, use that otherwise fail.

Your problem is that your `operator<<(std::ostream&, baz::Bar&)` is defined in the global namespace rather than in the namespace where `Bar` is defined (in this case `baz`). Putting the overload into namespace `baz` is needed anyway when using the operator from a template with a name depending on a template argument: in that case the first stage is omitted and only names found by argument dependent look-up are detected.

BTW, while fixing the location of the output operator you might want to consider passing the argument as `baz::Bar const&` as output operators normally don't modify the formatted entity.

Comment: You say from the current scope outwards, so does regular lookup stop when it finds the first function? Why doesn't it find the global one?

Comment: 0x499602D2: The look-up starting at the current context stops when it finds the first function with the corresponding name. In the example the search for `operator<<` stops when `goo::operator<<` is found and the global namespace is never searched (when removing `goo::operator<<` the global namespace _is_ searched). Since the arguments also involve namespace `std` (from the first argument) and namespace `baz` (from the second argument) names in either of these namespace are added from the second part (ADL). None of the the thus added `operator<<` functions is a match for `baz::Bar`, though.